# Which one of these two SELECT statment are correct?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, where-clause, sql-like

I am a little bit confusing and have no idea which one of these two SELECT statments are correct

```
SELECT Value FROM visibility WHERE site_info LIKE '%site_is_down%';
```

OR

```
SELECT Value FROM visibility WHERE site_info = 'site_is_down';
```

SInce I run both of these I get same result, but I am interesting which one is correct since `Value` column is `VARCHAR` data type OR both of these `SELECT` are incorect ?

Result set running first `SELECT`

```
       Value
   1.   0
```

Result set running second `SELECT`

```
    Value
1.   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two statements do not do the same thing.

The first statement filters on rows whose `site_info`s *contain* string `'site_is_down'`. The surrounding `'%'` are wildcards. So it would match on something like `'It looks like site_is_down right now'`.

The second query, with the equality condition, filters on `site_info` whose content is *exactly* `'site_is_dow'`.

Everything that the second query is also returned by the first query - but the opposite is not true.

Which statement is "correct" depends on your actual requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If both queries are useful for you, I'd use the second query, as it is the simplest, and runs faster.